# How can i show a the text after the character '-' from a field many2one in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

Actually I'm working in a custom module, I want to show the text after the caracter '-' in a field many2one that has a relation with the model res_partner.

[image: Example actual system]

In the field many2one "partner_shipping_ids", I want to show only the text after the character '-'
It is posible make this?

Answer (score 0):

from you requirement, you need to write a name_get method for this, for example:

```
@api.depends('name')
def name_get(self):
    res = []
    for record in self:
        name = record.name
        res.append((record.id, name))
    return res
```

Here, you can give name = whatever you need to show in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I write this answer in a context of `res.partner` object.

You can achieve this with the overriding `name_get()` method. You can use the `name_get()` method inside addons/base module. File location: addons/base/models/res_partner.py

Review additional prepared method: `_get_name(self):`

Key Points:

- Override method will replace existing dropdown display on the all form views (sale, purchase, accounting, etc).
- If you want to display a specific form view, then pass context to identify and override it. Return super/existing behavior for all the other cases. (Check in `_get_name()` method in above mentioned file)